# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'children' ismarked is required in 'ReactNativeModal'. value is undefined'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-apollo

I tried adding the plugin react native capital into my project. and I got this warning at my expo

```
 <Button transparent onPress={() => this.openVendor()}>
                        <Icon name="ios-list" style={{ color: '#fff' }} />
                    </Button>
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <Modal
                isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 1}
                animationIn={'slideInUp'}
                animationOut={'slideOutDown'}
            >
                {this.renderVendor()}
            </Modal>
```

Comment: This is a message from PropTypes. It means that the children (or contents of the JSX component) are required. Likely your this.renderVendor method is at some point returning null. You can change your code to {this.renderVendor() || </>} to ensure a child is passed.

Comment: thats not working for me @KeeganTeetaert

Comment: Is the button inside the **static navigationOptions** of the component? I have had a similar issue that the function called by **onPress** was only evaluated after the button had already been rendered.